# How to convert linestrip into triangles

Tags: conversion, svg

I have imported a SVG path:

[image: SVG imported path]

now I'd like to convert this path into triangles. For example below the path is converted into two triangles.

[image]

How should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. The shape above should convert into 2 triangles, but I'm happy even if is not optimized and creates more triangles than necessary

Comment: I still don't get it. Something like this? http://s14.postimg.org/yha6ppupd/2016_10_27_14_50_59.png

Comment: You may also elaborate your question using grease pencil by drawing what you want to achieve, if it's drawable.

Comment: @Highstaker eventhough your suggestion does not break up all triangles I think it might be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have can convert your "curve object" to "mesh object" (select your object, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, convert mesh from curve/meta/surf/text). Then you can do triangles in many ways. By hand, go to edit mode (press <kbd>Tab</kbd>) > press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> > mesh select vertices > then shift click on 3 vertices you want to do a triangle and press <kbd>F</kbd>. An automatic way, can be, with the object converted to mesh and en edit mode, press A until you select all object > press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill > press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate.